# Unity VRTK asset error

Tags: unity-game-engine, error-handling, textures, vrtk

I've just downloaded `VRTK v3.20` asset in unity but after importing I am gettin some errors. I can't seem to find a solution online.

**Unity Version**: 2018.1.6f1 personal 64bit.

Errors:

> 1.VRTK/Scripts/Interactions/Highlighters/VRTK_MaterialColorSwapHighlighte.cs(146,66): error CS1540: Cannot access protected member UnityEngine.Texture.Texture()' via a qualifier of typeUnityEngine.Texture'. The qualifier must be of type `VRTK.Highlighters.VRTK_MaterialColorSwapHighlighter' or derived from it
>
> 2.VRTK/Scripts/Interactions/Highlighters/VRTK_MaterialColorSwapHighlighte.cs(146,66): error CS0122: `UnityEngine.Texture.Texture()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

This is the line with an error:

```
renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", new Texture());
```

Answer (score 0):

VRTK 3.2.0 from the asset store doesn't support Unity 2018.1. You will need to get VRTK 3.3.0 from the Github page, use the master branch:

https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK